# which is the best media player to watch playlist video

Tags: windows-7, media-player

I have many video tutorials and i want simple player , where i have playlist visible on left and video on right. i could not found any good player.

Usually all player have separate window for playlist which is not visible

any ideas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Splayer](http://www.splayer.org/index.en.html)** has an integrated playlist window right next to the video window.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could use [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) as it has a seperate window for playlist.

Comment: VLC is a very good player, though I use portable version and it often takes a lot of time doing font cache . . .

Comment: If you actually throw a playlist of a lot of videos (and other file matches, like JPGs), VLC won't ever last through a party. Ever. Any version. Ever. I wouldn't recommend this for hardcore use. I'm coming to this page because VLC and MPC are both insufficient for my playlists.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, if you're running Windows 7, you'll want to use Windows Media Player, particularly since many videos online are .wmv files (which plays on WMP) or are usually compatible with the player. It's also relatively easy to use and build video playlists in. You might as well use what has come with your computer.

Answer (score 0):

[Gomplayer](http://www.gomlab.com/eng/) do this as you explain. Open GomPlayer then press F8. Playlist window will appear.  Separate window for playlist but visible